# Integrate .SWF file(flash game) in Android Native(java)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, shockwave, geckoview

I want to play flash format game(with .swf extension) in my native android app. I tried this using Android webView and geckoview but I didn't find any success.
Is there any android library available for playing flash games that I can use to solve my problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. I already have an existing Android app. I just want to add the _flash file run_ feature to it. And now I can't re-create my entire app on Adobe AIR or any other SDK again from the scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is no longer available to download since December 31, 2020, and Adobe starts blocking Flash content from running altogether on January 12, 2021. The company recommends that you uninstall Flash entirely as a matter of security. There will be no more updates to Flash, nor will you be able to download old versions directly from Adobe.
So now you can't integrate Flash files in Android Apps directly nor you can use as a service. End of the Story :(